# Simple way to get the DOMElement for associated ViewModel (KnockoutJS)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

### Description

I have a viewModel which contains an array.

Now i want to get the associated dom element for one item in my array.

#### Question: How can i get the DOM Element for one item in my array ?

### Sample

```
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

#### Simple UI

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><span data-bind="text: id"></span></li>
</ul>

<button>click me</button>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // define demo viewModel
    var ViewModel = function (name) {
        self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable(name);
        self.items = ko.observableArray();
    };

    // define demo itemsModel
    var ItemsModel = function (id) {
        self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(id);
    };

    // create viewModel
    var viewModel = new ViewModel("Hello World!");

    // push some items
    viewModel.items.push(new ItemsModel(1));
    viewModel.items.push(new ItemsModel(2));
    viewModel.items.push(new ItemsModel(3));

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            var itemsModel = viewModel.items()[1];
            var id = itemsModel.id();

            // how can i get the <li> element ?
            var domElement = ???;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you reall need to reach specific item that way ? If you dont you can use click binding for this purpose:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click:function(event,data){ itemClick(this,event) }">Click Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>


var ViewModel = function (name) {
        ...

        this.itemClick(item,event) {      

          // You can reach the clicked item like this $(event.currentTarget)  
          console.log($(event.currentTarget));

        };

        ...
}
```

**EDIT :**

Or you can use attr binding and reach specific element via jquery :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="attr: {'liId': id}">
        <span data-bind="text: id"></span>         
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then inside the button click function reach the li with item's id property:

$("li[liId=1]");

Check out for more information this [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)